# Hive installation on cluster

Tags: hive

I have installed 4 node **Hadoop cluster**. And installed **hive** v0.11 on name node. Now I would like access the Hive from outside the cluster for creating the tables and querying . How to access from Hive client what are the pre requisites on client.

Answer (score 1):

the hive client has the following requirements:

- Hive client software installed - you can download from apache for version 0.11
- You need to provide to hive the connectivity information for the JobTracker and NameNode of the Hadoop cluster where your Hive tables will be stored and the Map/Reduce jobs are going to run. These are provided by supplyoing the HADOOP_HOME that includes those pieces of info in the mapred-site.xml and core-site.xml.

In addition you need to have the hive-site.xml configured.

Following below shows the basics of the hive-site.xml that contains that information
 - You need to provide the info for the Hive MetaStore that contains info about your hive tables

```
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.local</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
```

or if you are on a cluster

```
    <property>
        <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
        <value>thrift://metastore-server:9083,thrift://metastore-server2:9083,thrift://metastoe-server3:9083</value>
</property>
```

There are several parameters required for setting up the jdbc connection for the hive metastore. Here is one of them - look for similar ones in the hive-site.xml

```
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
    <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>

    <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>
```